# Repeated Measures ANOVA in python

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, python

I have been looking to do Repeated Measures ANOVA in python.
But it has been really difficult to find a python library that has this functionality.

I also want to state that there are 2 ways for Repeated Measures:

1) Traditional way - treat it as a multivariate test, each response is considered a separate variable

2) other approach to do it mixed model

I know that the python package statsmodels contains the mixed model,
but I have not seen an example of how to do Repeated Measures ANOVA.
The traditional ANOVA method for repeated measures does not seem to be in this statistical library.

Hope someone is familiar with some Python library that can do Repeated Measures ANOVA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also think your best (and probably only) bet is the library [Statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/index.html). `Statsmodels` contains a [linear mixed effects model](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/mixed_linear.html) routine.

Having said that you can bite the bullet now and look into [calling R from within Python](https://sites.google.com/site/aslugsguidetopython/data-analysis/pandas/calling-r-from-python). The package [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/index.html) seems to be the basic computational bed-rock for this. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used rpy2 in the past with python. But I am trying to get a platform where it is purely Python. I don't want to install R-stats running as a server.

Comment: I am glad I could help; if this is post is useful for you or answers your original question please consider upvoting it or accepting it as an answer.

Comment: I will upvote your questions for sure, but I will wait a bit in terms of accepting it as an answer.

Comment: The doc for rpy2 has moved to http://rpy2.readthedocs.org/en/version_2.7.x/

Comment: It's easy to call R from within inotebook, I think it's called...